# Auto_route & build_runner disable NullSafety

Tags: flutter, build-runner

I'm trying to use auto_route library with build_runner, but each time my build_runner generate my router.gr.dart file, it does generate code with null safety, while I'm not using it in my project.

Is there a way to tell build_runner to generate code without NullSafety feature ?